# How do you breed an Opal Dragon in Dragonvale?

Tags: dragonvale

It's October and I see the Opal Dragon in the marketplace for purchase. What is the best dragon breeding pair to obtain this Gem dragon, and what is the breeding time?

Comment: I just went on dragon vale and saw that to! I searched on google how to breed an opal draon and it said it was coming soon it was the first link just keep waiting and it will be ready.......

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [Dragonvale Breeding Guide](http://www.dragonvalebreedingguide.com/comment/3140), you use Lava and Mud dragons and it takes 31 hours.